# How do i use rank in ssrs reports

Tags: sql

i need to assign tied ranks same row number
Like

A 1

B 1

C 3

in reporting ssrs

Comment: I want it to be like.

A 1

B 1

C 3

Comment: You might want to add the input (for your expected output) as well. However, your expected output looks rather like **RANK**ed, not **DENSE_RANK**ed. Did you check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms173825.aspx?